# ActiveMQ redhat limited connections

Tags: activemq-classic, redhat

we are using activeMQ5.11.1 on REDHAT 6.5 server enterprise with kernel 2.6.32
we open two transports, TCP and STOMP
clients send requests to queue using stomp and consumer is consuming the requests through tcp. we face this exception after 140 connections opened

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
  at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
  at   org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readLine(StompWireFormat.java:186)
 at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:94
```

we don't face this exception on Centos nor windows boxes.
i tried some env parameters like ulimit -n 10240 but no reflect happened.

any guidance to follow please ?